# Remove keywords from one text file if they're listed in another?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, grep, command

I have two different text files:

```
foo.txt - This file contains a list of 500 keywords.
bar.txt - This file contains a list of 230 keywords.
```

I need to compare the files in some way to get a list of all the keywords that aren't contained in BOTH files.

For example, if a keyword is in the file `foo.txt` but not in the file `bar.txt`, then I need to know that keyword.

I was thinking that the easiest way to do this would be via command line with sed or grep, but I'm opened to any suggestions or help.  Thanks!

Comment: Are these keywords in separate lines?

Comment: If they are on separate lines you can just use `grep -Fwf foo.txt bar.txt` command.

Comment: are the words in same file unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniq <(sort foo.txt bar.txt)
```

Will do it for you (if your keywords are on separate lines).

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at `diff`

```
cat f1
blue
green
yellow
```

```
cat f2
orange
red
green
```

```
diff -y f1 f2
blue                                                          | orange
                                                              > red
green                                                           green
yellow                                                        <
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just have 300-500 words in a file, performance is not an issue at all. you can just:

```
grep -vFwf f1 f2 > result.txt
grep -vFwf f2 f1 >>result.txt
```